# gt table coloring full column with row filter

Tags: r, gt

Has anyone had the following issue with gt table?

Regardless of the value I set for the tab style row argument the whole column gets hit with the color argument. I only want the "Paid Per Episode" column to color it blue when it is greater than 33000.

Could this be something with R markdown?

```
hip_dt_epsd_table %>% 
  rename(State = JUR_ST_ABBR_PRIM, Episodes = epsd_count, "Paid Per Episode" = pd_per_epsd, "Episodes Outlier" = epsd_outlier, 
         "Paid Per Episode Outlier" = pd_epsd_outlier, 
         "Episodes 99th Percentile" = epsd_count_99th) %>%
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_currency(columns=vars("Paid Per Episode","Paid Per Episode Outlier")) %>%
  fmt_number(columns=vars("Episodes","Episodes Outlier","Episodes 99th Percentile"),sep_mark=",", drop_trailing_zeros = TRUE) %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "lightblue"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = "Paid Per Episode",
      row = "Paid Per Episode" > 33000))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide an example I have used `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(gt)

mtcars %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = "lightblue"),
            locations = cells_body(columns = "disp",rows = disp > 250))
```

[image]

Comment: Why the difference in expressing the columns as a string "disp" vs a variable for rows?

Comment: That is the syntax that the function follows. btw `columns` also works with `vars` without passing it as a string. i.e `locations = cells_body(columns = vars(disp),rows = disp > 250)`